# TesseractNotFoundError: **Path to tesseract executable** ArchLinux(ManjoraLinux)

Tags: python, python-tesseract

As the title says, I am having trouble with pytesseract not being able to find tesseract in path..?

I have already installed tesseract using pamac-manager.

Comment: Can you run the command "tesseract" from the shell?  If not, you need to fix your path so that you can.

Comment: @FrankYellin yes I can. But the problem still persists.